# I need a function which returns division result of two column values?

Tags: php, arrays

So I have this array output:

```
    [period5] => Array
        (
            [SI] => 0
            [B K] => 0
            [FS] => 0
            [DD] => 3
            [score_counter_SI] => 0
            [score_counter_B K] => 0
            [score_counter_FS] => 0
            [score_counter_DD] => 1
        )
    [period6] => Array
        (
            [SI] => 6
            [B K] => 0
            [FS] => 0
            [DD] => 0
            [score_counter_SI] => 2
            [score_counter_B K] => 0
            [score_counter_FS] => 0
            [score_counter_DD] => 0
        )
etc
```

And I need to output JS for Google, where the values in between the single quotes are just the string representations of the numbers (I am getting a divide by zero error and I don't need the `score_counter_xx` in the output)

```
['period5', 0, '0', 0, '0', 0, '0', 3, '3'],
['period6', 3, '3', 0 '0', 0, '0', 0, '0'],
```

So I need the results of ($key[0]/$key[4]), ($key[1]/$key[5]),  ($key[2]/$key[6]), ($key[3]/$key[7])

The php loop I have now:

```
   $return = '';
   foreach($inputArray as $period =>$values) {
       $return .= "['".$period."'";
       foreach($values as $key => $value) {
           if($value['score_counter_'.$key] >0) {//Prevent Divide by Zero
               $return .= ($value[$key]/$value['score_counter_'.$key]).", '".($value[$key]/$value['score_counter_'.$key])."'";
           }
       }
       $return .= "]";
   }
   echo $return;
```

But all the divisions are blank?

Comment: What is your problem with your PHP code? Beside that the array structure is different to the one you provided.

Comment: Perhaps the `if` condition is not being satisfied for any of the kay-value pairs?

Comment: I am getting no output. just the periods. So only `['period5']['period6']` and this part of my php code does nothing: `($value[$key]/$value['score_counter'.$key])`

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by concatenating strings. Construct an array and then call `json_encode()`.

Comment: @pgngp for period 6, score_counter_SI = 2 so i would expect my php would parse: [SI] => 6 / [score_counter_SI] => 2 = 3 so it reads: 3, '3'

Comment: @Barmar it looks like JSON but it isn't JSON. I am using it for a Google Chart and depending on the chart visualisation I need to add values like annotations or tooltips

Comment: Are you missing an underscore in `$value['score_counter'.$key]`? Is it supposed to be `$value['score_counter_'.$key]`

Comment: Tx, it was a typo, i am staring a bit too long at this seemily simple array loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `$value[$key]`. `$value` is a number, not an array. You should just use `$value` there, and `$values['score_counter_'.$key]` for the element you want to divide by. You also forgot the `_` in that key.

Instead of constructing the JSON array by concatenating strings, use `json_encode()`.

```
$return = array();
foreach($inputArray as $period =>$values) {
   $temp = array($period);
   foreach($values as $key => $value) {
        $other_key = 'score_counter_'.$key;
        if (isset($values[$other_key]) && $values[$other_key] > 0) // prevent divide by 0
            $quotient = $value / $values[$other_key];
        } else {
            $quotient = 0;
        }
        array_push($temp, $quotient, (string)$quotient);
    }
    $return[] = $temp;
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Tx, you help me out a lot i think i am going to need this. I am going to try and incorporate it in my current code. (It's a bit late and I am making stupid mistakes). I just need the divisions numbers  and I am almost following  your procces.

PS; i am not trying to output a JSON object as just simple row data for a Google chart

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google Charts, but I'd be very surprised if it doesn't actually want JSON data. Can you link to the documentation that shows this data format instead?

Comment: you are correct there's also a JSON way but I opt for the simpler direct way after 14 charts I stuck (litteraly) with it. I might need to rewrite it to JSON, but the simpler way is easier to read. [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_toJSON) see the data.addRows([ code part. That is the way I am plotting the charts right now.